# How to add data from list of values to each dataframe in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of 263 dataframes, too each one I would like to add a column that repeats the phrase from a chr list of the same length. Here is a simplified example.

```
#create mock data
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(4, 5, 6), y2 = c(7, 8, 9))
d4 <- data.frame(y1 = c(6, 5, 4), y2 = c(9, 8, 7))
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

> my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4

[[3]]
  y1 y2
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9

[[4]]
  y1 y2
1  6  9
2  5  8
3  4  7


Simulation<- c("100", "131", "121", "146")

> Simulation
[1] "100" "131" "121" "146"
```

So to each data frame I would like to add a column "Simulation" and repeat the name of that simulation within the column, as below:

```
> my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2 Simulation
1  1  4        100
2  2  5        100
3  3  6        100

[[2]]
  y1 y2 Simulation
1  3  6        131
2  2  5        131
3  1  4        131

[[3]]
  y1 y2 Simulation
1  4  7        121
2  5  8        121
3  6  9        121

[[4]]
  y1 y2 Simulation
1  6  9        146
2  5  8        146
3  4  7        146
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create a new column by looping over the corresponding elements of the 'my.list' and the `vector` 'Simulation'

```
Map(cbind, my.list, Simulation = Simulation)
```

---

Or with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(my.list, Simulation, ~ .x %>%
                             mutate(Simulation = .y))
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast way could be:

```
for(i in 1:length(my.list))
{
  my.list[[i]]$simulation <- Simulation[i]
}

[[1]]
  y1 y2 simulation
1  1  4        100
2  2  5        100
3  3  6        100

[[2]]
  y1 y2 simulation
1  3  6        131
2  2  5        131
3  1  4        131

[[3]]
  y1 y2 simulation
1  4  7        121
2  5  8        121
3  6  9        121

[[4]]
  y1 y2 simulation
1  6  9        146
2  5  8        146
3  4  7        146
```

Comment: As far as I know `for` loops and `apply` based solutions have similar performance.  Not clear why you mentioned `fast way` when it is a `for` loop